# Cape Verde: any safety alerts regarding hasslers, con men, thieves or muggers specific to this region?

Tags: safety, cape-verde

I'm travelling to Cape Verde (Cabo Verde in Portuguese) & want to know what expectations I should have regarding possible hasslers, con men, thieves or muggers.

Some countries/locations in the world definitely have specific issues for travellers, for instance, a lot of hasslers in Morocco, or another example, many thieves/pick-pockets in Paris.

Is there such a thing I should pay particular attention to in Cape Verde? ie. beware of muggers in some specifics locations?

Note: before posting this question, I checked that [it was "on topic"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (safety topic in this case) & really focussed my concern on very specific subsets of the "safety" topic.

Comment: You'll have noticed on that 'on topic' page that asking for recommendations are not...I'll edit your question to help

Comment: Please do. Note that I'll answer myself to this question as I just went to travel there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasslers: cape verdean people never ever hassle tourists, they are extremely laid back people who will simply let you visit their shop and browse through the products and only help you if you ask. However, there are more and more immigrants from Senegal who do hassle tourist, they are a minority of the population but do have a negative impact on the touristy business environment in that regard I believe.

Thieves: most of the country is very safe in that regard, however in bigger cities such as Mindello and Praia, you definitely have to watch out as soon as it is dark. In those cities, you better take a taxi as soon as you're out of the very policed areas.

Muggers: same as what I wrote regarding thieves above.

Con men: I haven't heard and haven't come across any. If anything, someone may overcharge you maybe 20 or 30% in a shop, for a tour, but I have been told by locals and expats that this did not happen often.